# Createjs masking with drawRect not working in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-canvas, createjs

I want to cut out some squares from a picture.
The problem is that `Createjs` masking with `drawRect` is not working in Safari.
Please check the following codepen in Safari

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moXXRN
```

It works on all the browsers except Safari

Comment: Confirmed, but this might be a Safari/Canvas bug. You are using a negative width rectangle to wind the large rectangle backwards, which is a creative solution to doing cut-outs. I will confirm if Safari's canvas supports this and report back.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this is not masking or EaselJS, but how Safari handles winding rectangles drawn with negative coordinates. It looks like most browsers treat a rectangle with a one negative dimension as drawn in reverse, but Safari does not.

A super [simple canvas example](https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/WmzXaJ) has the same problem:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(50,50,50,50);
ctx.rect(150, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.rect(300, 0, 350, -350);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

In most browsers, this draws the cut-out area. Safari does not.

Your solution of using your own `lineTo()` commands is a good workaround.

Comment: Hi Lanny, Yes you are correct..  Thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it worked in Safari using `lineTo` and `moveTo` functions instead of `drawRect`

e.g.

```
shape.graphics.moveTo( 50, 50 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 100, 50 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 100, 100 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 50, 100 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 50, 50 );

shape.graphics.moveTo( 300, 0 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 0, 0 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 0, 300 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 300, 300 );
shape.graphics.lineTo( 300, 0 );
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMEZMx